# ОС пропала из boot меню в bios

Tags: загрузка

На ноутбуке установлено две ОС (Windows 8.1 и Debian 7). После установки пароля на boot меню и на юзеров, пункт загрузки grub, через который загружался Debian, пропал. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вернуть этот пункт

Comment: Попробуйте переустановить grub. Или update-grub

Comment: Так в том-то и дело, что я могу только windows загрузить, до grub никак не добраться

Comment: Два варианта - либо вы shift слишком поздно начинали жать, либо - восстановите Grub. Сделать это можно через LiveCD. Желательно - тоже от Debian'а, но можно и другой. Если от Debian'а, то, скорее всего, там будет пункт "Rescue" или как-то так. В общем опция для восстановления. Тогда Grub, скорее всего, можно будет восстановить автоматически. Если же такой опции нет - загрузитесь в LiveCD и восстановите его самостоятельно (вероятно будет достаточно просто установить его заново).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за внимание, просто полностью переустановил все системы на компьютере

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы открыть меню `grub` нужно зажать левый `shift` после загрузки `BIOS`

Comment: Держал шифт минуты три, ничего не произошло